# Calling landlines, and capturing keystrokes

Tags: java, call, sip

I'm looking for a way to make a program, that calls specified numbers, and plays a sound message. The callee will be asked to press a button on his phone, and the program then has to be able to capture which button was pressed.

I currently have a working solution, using Voicent, but I find it to be unstable, and I would like more control over the process, not to mention a solution integrated in java.

The protocol used to call must be SIP.

I have looked around for a java-solution, and found among others mjsip, which looks promising, but I don't see a posibility to capture the keystrokes.

So the question is, does there exist any solution(preferably something implemented in java), where I can capture the pressed keystrokes?

Furthermore, if it is possible, I would like to have the ability to delay the playing of the sound file, until the callee talks into the phone.

Comment: I have looked through the JDOCs of mjsip, and I did not find anything relevant to my problem. Other than that, I have read the "peers" documentation, where I didn't find anything either. And I have searched the internet, but I could not find anyone with the same problem(I assume it is my searching capabilities that has failed, because this seems to be a pretty basic problem)

Comment: I think that most people would solve this problem by scripting [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/).